# Did I solve this graph transformation correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, transformation

I have to shift this equation to the right 3 units and then up 2 units. My original equation is in the number 1 box in Desmos. The equation is y=\sqrt{x^{3}-x}[image: grap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{3}-x},$ then for a shift to the right $3$ units and then up $2$ units you have $$f(x-3)+2.$$

This gives $f(x-3)+2=\sqrt{(x-3)^{2}-(x-3)}+2. $ ([Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/frpw7jkwvq) for the graph)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The original equation is y=\sqrt{x^{3}-x}.

Comment: Sure, I've fixed my answer!

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That is really weird how you have to do -3 on the x^3 and x. I will have to figure out why that is. Normally in an equation you just have to change one x and it's done.

Comment: You're welcome! Try to visualise it with a simpler graph first (e.g a straight line). Also see (https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-positive-value-of-h-shift-a-graph-to-the-left-and-not-the-right)

Comment: Great I will do that. Thank you!